# How to show real time traffic data for a particular route on Google map in ios

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, distance, directions

I have implemented direction API to find out a route from source to destination using Google Maps in IOS swift 3.0.

I want to display traffic direction route with traffic data as different colour in Polyline stroke Colour. But i unable to show the route with different colour as traffic data colour.

Here is my output.
[image: Here is my output]

And i want to show like this.
 [image: And i want to show like this]

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward API. However there are a couple options.

Render the Google Maps element in a WebView and use the Google JavaScript API to enable the traffic layer. The downside of this approach is that the UX likely wont be as nice as native programming. The upside is less coding.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#TrafficLayer

Call another traffic provider's REST API and overlay on top of the native iOS map component.

Comment: how did you achieve it?